# d3.js select nodes and change their style

Tags: d3.js

I have this code containing nodes and links that shows a linked map of nodes..

```
d3sparql.graph = function(json, config) {
  var head = json.head.vars
  var data = json.results.bindings

  var opts = {
    "key1":   config.key1   || head[0] || "key1",
    "key2":   config.key2   || head[1] || "key2",
    "label1": config.label1 || head[2] || false,  // optional
    "label2": config.label2 || head[3] || false,  // optional
  }
  var graph = {
    "nodes": [],
    "links": []
  }
  var check = d3.map()
  var index = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var key1 = data[i][opts.key1].value
    var key2 = data[i][opts.key2].value
    var label1 = opts.label1 ? data[i][opts.label1].value : key1
    var label2 = opts.label2 ? data[i][opts.label2].value : key2
    if (!check.has(key1)) {
      graph.nodes.push({"key": key1, "label": label1})
      check.set(key1, index)
      index++
    }
    if (!check.has(key2)) {
      graph.nodes.push({"key": key2, "label": label2})
      check.set(key2, index)
      index++
    }
    graph.links.push({"source": check.get(key1), "target": check.get(key2)})
  }
  return graph
}
```

What I want to achieve is to modify the styles of the nodes (color and size..)

I tried to insert this before the `return graph`

```
d3.selectAll(graph.nodes).style("fill", "black");
d3.selectAll(graph.nodes).attr("r", 30);
```

Which doesn't work.. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to make a fiddle, then we could do something on it...

Comment: thanks: here it is https://jsfiddle.net/1ya0g9gr/1/

Comment: i'm not an expert of fiddler neither, it doens't work as on my machine, but the result could be seen on this page: http://biohackathon.org/d3sparql/ by   navigating graph-> d3forcegraph and selecting view cache or query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select elements by data in D3. `.selectAll()` takes a [CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to select the DOM elements. So you have to select the elements by name/class that you've added before that represent that data.